# Switching USB DWC3 controller from host to device mode

Tags: usb, embedded-linux, usb-otg

I need to use an embedded Linux platform as a USB device in order to stream audio and video from a smartphone. The platform has a USB A receptacle and doesn't support OTG (USB_ID pin is not connected on the host controller).

Now I try to switch from host to device mode using DWC3 controller and the debugfs interface. Therefore I activated DWC3 controller in the kernel configuration and set it to "Dual Role Mode". After mounting the file system I checked the current mode in `/sys/kernel/debug/xxxxxxxx.usb3/mode` with `cat mode` and got host as expected. But unfortunately I can't write device to the mode file. After entering the command `echo device > mode` it remains host and does not change. Does anyone know what could be causing it?

Comment: Are you talking about Intel based tablet PCs? Read this blog post: https://hansdegoede.livejournal.com/25342.html

Comment: @0andriy how is that related to the question?

Comment: With the information provided, it is hard to guess what the problem is. 
Did you get messages in the syslog / dmesg? The DWC driver usually tells you there, what his problem is.
You should also check in the datasheet of your USB Controller if it is at least a dual-role controller, otherwise you won't be able to switch the mode.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this used to work out of the box, but with the kernel version I'm using in an embedded platform (5.4.0) it doesn't.  In order to make it work I had to patch around a bug in the kernel:

```
diff --git a/drivers/usb/dwc3/core.c b/drivers/usb/dwc3/core.c
index bf1a7a9da..a78990664 100644
--- a/drivers/usb/dwc3/core.c
+++ b/drivers/usb/dwc3/core.c
@@ -110,9 +110,6 @@ static void __dwc3_set_mode(struct work_struct *work)
    unsigned long flags;
    int ret;
 
-   if (dwc->dr_mode != USB_DR_MODE_OTG)
-       return;
-
    if (dwc->current_dr_role == DWC3_GCTL_PRTCAP_OTG)
        dwc3_otg_update(dwc, 0);
 
@@ -192,6 +189,12 @@ void dwc3_set_mode(struct dwc3 *dwc, u32 mode)
    dwc->desired_dr_role = mode;
    spin_unlock_irqrestore(&dwc->lock, flags);
 
+   if (dwc->dr_mode != USB_DR_MODE_OTG)
+   {
+       __dwc3_set_mode(&dwc->drd_work);
+       return;
+   }
+
    queue_work(system_freezable_wq, &dwc->drd_work);
 }
```

After applying the above patch, rebooting to the new kernel, and running:

```
echo "host" | sudo tee /sys/kernel/debug/*.usb3/mode
```

I was able to switch modes like I expect (note: I had *.dwc3 instead of *.usb3 in the above command).